# Does module pattern in javascript store variables?

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

```js
const Formatter = (function() {
  let timesRun = 0;
  
  const log = (message) => console.log(`[${Date.now()}] Logger: ${message}`);
  const setTimesRun = () => {
    log("Setting times run");
    ++timesRun;
    console.log(timesRun);
  }

  const makeUppercase = (text) => {
    log("Making uppercase");
    setTimesRun();
    return text.toUpperCase();
  };

  return {
    makeUppercase,
    timesRun,
  }
})()

console.log(Formatter.makeUppercase("tomek"));
console.log(Formatter.timesRun);

console.log(Formatter.makeUppercase("foo"));
console.log(Formatter.timesRun);

console.log(Formatter.makeUppercase("hey"));
console.log(Formatter.timesRun);
```

With `console.log(Formatter.timesRun);` I'm expecting the incremented value of timesRun. However, it keeps logging 0. Using `console.log(timesRun);` inside the `setRimesRun()` function logs the incremented value. I don't understand where the data is stored and why am I getting 0.

I thought `timesRun` was always 0 and I added `console.log(timesRun);` to test it. It showed the incremeneted value which confused the me even more.

Comment: You're storing numbers in two separate locations: the variable and the object property.

Comment: The `timesRun` property in `{makeUppercase, timesRun}` is a copy of the number in `let timesRun`, copied when you created the return value from the function. It won't change if you set (separate variable) `timesRun` to something else. Simpler example: `let timesRun = 4; let temp = {timesRun}; timesRun = 8; //temp.timesRun is still 4, the value of the property when it was created`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `timesRun` is locally in the method `setTimesRun`. You should use the one outside of `setTimesRun`, so `Formatter.timesRun`.

You can do like that:

```js
const Formatter = (function() {
  var timesRun = 0;
  const log = (message) => console.log(`[${Date.now()}] Logger: ${message}`);
  const setTimesRun = () => {
    Formatter.timesRun++;
    log("Setting times run to " + timesRun);
    //console.log(timesRun);
  }

  const makeUppercase = (text) => {
    log("Making uppercase");
    setTimesRun();
    return text.toUpperCase();
  };

  return {
    makeUppercase,
    timesRun,
  }
})()

console.log(Formatter.makeUppercase("tomek"));
console.log(Formatter.timesRun);

console.log(Formatter.makeUppercase("foo"));
console.log(Formatter.timesRun);

console.log(Formatter.makeUppercase("hey"));
console.log(Formatter.timesRun);
```

Here, all times I'm using the same variable: `Formatter.timesRun`. With this, all logger use the same and will some same instance of this int

Answer (score 0):

your misunderstanding: `var a = 5, b = a;` then `a = 10;` and wondering why b is still 5 and not 10? `Formatter.timesRun` is not the same thing as `let timesRun` which you increment.

The variable changes, but you never update the object property.

Check out [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```js
const Formatter = (function() {
  let timesRun = 0;
  
  const log = (message) => console.log(`[${Date.now()}] Logger: ${message}`);
  const setTimesRun = () => {
    log("Setting times run");
    ++timesRun;
    console.log(timesRun);
  }

  const makeUppercase = (text) => {
    log("Making uppercase");
    setTimesRun();
    return text.toUpperCase();
  };

  return {
    makeUppercase,
    get timesRun(){
      return timesRun
    },
  }
})()

console.log(Formatter.makeUppercase("tomek"));
console.log(Formatter.timesRun);

console.log(Formatter.makeUppercase("foo"));
console.log(Formatter.timesRun);

console.log(Formatter.makeUppercase("hey"));
console.log(Formatter.timesRun);
```